# Dropping of block on vertical spring to compare the falling and returning height

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, spring

If a block falls from $X$ height to the spring in ground,the spring compresses then expands depending on its stiffness, that is block bounces back to the $Y$ height. Is it possible to make the block bounces more than $X$ height ($Y>X$).

Comment: By conservation of energy it would be obvious you cannot. Unless of course you supply some energy.

Answer (score 1):

if the spring is standing still, the answer is no. the spring simply stores up the energy of the falling block, brings its motion to a halt, and then gives that stored energy right back to the block. the best one could expect if the spring were perfect and in the absence of any form of friction would be for the mass to bounce back to exactly the same height from which it was originally released. since no spring is ideal and friction is always present, the bounced block will always miss the mark and be returned to a slightly lower height than that from which it was originally dropped.

Comment: For example:If block of 10kg dropping on the spring having stiffness of 500 N/m from the height of 10m.Then how height the block bounce back(Neglect air resistance)?

Comment: assume energy is conserved. equate the stored energy in the spring with the kinetic energy of the block when it hits. equate this stored energy to the potential energy of the block  after it bounces off and returns.